# How to give EOF on Ubuntu, Ctrl-D does not seem to work?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I have written the following code to print only one space if there are more than one space.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' '||c=='\t')
        {
            while(c==' '||c=='\t')
                c=getchar();
            putchar(' ');
            putchar(c);

        }   
        else
            putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to check your inner while() loop for getchar() returning EOF there ?

Comment: I know it is a Linux question, but in MSVC the equivalent `Ctrl-Z` must be the first keystroke after a newline.

Comment: No, no. The inner loop is just skipping the extra tab space or space.

Comment: I have edited the code and added extra line **putchar(c)** in if block and now the code magically seems to work.

Comment: Maybe it "magically" works now, but you still have not tested the input, when it is no longer a tab or a space, for `EOF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on a line, on its own, after a <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
or two <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>in a row.

```
./a.out
foo            bar<ENTER>
<Ctrl+D>
```

or

```
./a.out
foo         bar<Ctrl+D><Ctrl+D>
```